# Singleton changing integer

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a singleton I implement in this way:

```
PhotoViewController* sharedSingleton = [PhotoViewController sharedManager];
```

I know that to launch a method I have to do [sharedSingleton method];

but what if I want to change an integer declared in the PhotoViewController.h file as NSInteger* tagNumber, hoe can I do that? I tried this:

```
[sharedSingleton.tagNumber = 1];
```

but it doesn't work!

EDIT:

error: property tagNUmber not found on object of type photoViewController

```
@interface PhotoViewController : UIViewController{

BOOL newMedia;
UIPopoverController *popoverController;
DBRestClient *restClient;
NSInteger* tagNumber;
}

+ (PhotoViewController *) sharedManager;

@end
```

Comment: it can't be declared as NSInteger*.
If you want to access the tagNumber property you should declare it as @property (assign) NSInteger tagNumber
in the PhotoViewController.h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Singletons are regular objects.  The only difference is that only one instance will be created from the class.

If you aren't able to set the tagNumber it is likely that some other type of coding error is happening... perhaps the tagNumber property was declared in a class extension, making the accessor/mutator methods private?

If you edit your question with how the tagNumber is declared, and also include the error message you are getting, I'll be able to edit this answer and give you more specific advice.

**EDIT:** ...and yes, definitely double check to make sure you didn't declare the NSInteger to be a pointer... an NSInteger is a scalar type (so it takes a direct value, and doesn't use the dereference '*' operator).

I suggest using properties instead of accessing the instance variables directly:

```
@interface PhotoViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL newMedia;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIPopoverController *popoverController;
@property (nonatomic, strong) DBRestClient *restClient;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger tagNumber;

+ (PhotoViewController *) sharedManager;

@end
```

Then set the variable without the brackets as:

```
sharedSingleton.tagNumber = 1;
```

Comment: I used this: PhotoViewController* sharedSingleton = [PhotoViewController sharedManager];
                           sharedSingleton.tagNumber = 2;  but still when I NSLog it from the PhotoViewController it gives 0.

Comment: @interface PhotoViewController : UIViewController{
 
    BOOL newMedia;
    UIPopoverController *popoverController;
    DBRestClient *restClient;
}

+ (PhotoViewController *) sharedManager;      property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger tagNumber;

Comment: I didn't but the @ before the property because stack overflow didn't let me

Comment: If you have synthesized as well then you can access that via `[[PhotoViewController sharedManager] settagNumber:2];`

Comment: i have synthetised and then logged in PhotoViewController.m

Comment: Try to simplify your test.  Cut and paste this code... 

`PhotoViewController* sharedSingleton = [PhotoViewController sharedManager];

sharedSingleton.tagNumber = 1;

NSLog(@"The tagNumber is: %ld", (long)sharedSingleton.tagNumber);`

Comment: ok, it doesn't work if I do NSLog(@"%d", tagNumber); but it does if I do NSLog(@"The tagNumber is: %ld", (long)sharedSingleton.tagNumber); Can't understand why

Comment: Because your first isn't getting the tagNumber from the sharedSingleton object (unless that was a typo).